# Linked List C++ Class What is the diffence between these two add node implementations?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have written following class for linked list. There are two separate functions for adding new node (`addValue1` and `addValue2`). One uses pointer to node, another does not.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

class linkedList{
private:
    struct Node {
        int data;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head;

public:
    linkedList(){
       //constructor
        this->head = NULL;
    }

    ~linkedList(){
        //destructor
    }

    void addValue1(int n) {
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = n;
        newNode->next = head;
        this->head = newNode;
    }

    void addValue2(int n) {
        Node newNode;
        newNode.data = n;
        newNode.next = head;
        this->head = &newNode;
    }

    void print(){
        Node* curNode = this->head;
        while(this->head != NULL) {
            std::cout << curNode->data << " "<< std::endl;
            curNode = curNode->next;
        }
    }

};

int main() {


    linkedList llist;

    llist.addValue2(5);
    llist.addValue1(4);
    llist.addValue1(9);
    llist.print();

}
```

Which one of these two is recommended and why? Is there any difference between these two? If we don't use new operator, we don't need to use the delete operator later on. This seems like an advantage to me. Is it really?

Comment: ask youself, how long does `newNode` live in each function.

Comment: If one dereferences the value stored by `addValue2`, it would invoke undefined behavior, due to dereferencing the dangling pointer.

Answer (score 6):

`addValue2` will wreak havoc since you're storing a pointer to a node `newNode` which has *automatic storage duration*. The pointer `&newNode` will *dangle* once that goes out of scope.

**Boom!**

Note that it's also unfashionable to write the destructor out explicitly if that's what the compiler would do for you anyway. If you need to introduce the destructor in order to make it `virtual` then write

```
virtual ~linkedList() = default;
```

In your case though you will need to `delete` the nodes allocated with `new` else your class will leak memory.

Finally, if you don't want to worry about memory at all then use

```
typedef linkedList std::list;
```

and head off to the pub.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand. the print() function is printing the linked list correctly. when will addValue2 cause problem then?

Comment: @user87466 Dereferencing dangling pointers is undefined behavior. Always. It might _seem_ to work for one particular case, but is not guaranteed to. One cannot learn C++ by trial and error, due to multitude of possible use cases, which invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @user87466  Whenever the application exits from `addValue2` destructor of  `Node newNode` is evoked - thus, any other data can be randomly stored in its place. So the pointer to it that you stored will cause undefined behavior on use.

Comment: ***i did not understand. the print() function is printing the linked list correctly.*** Sometimes you get unlucky with Undefined Behavior and it produces the result you expect only to randomly crash or produce some other weird result.

Answer (score 3):

The two are very different. If one would rewrite your `addNode2` to use manual allocations instead of automatic it would look like this (original code as comments):

```
void addValue2(int n) {
    Node* newNode = Node();   // Node newNode;
    newNode->data = n;        // newNode.data = n;
    newNode->next = head;     // newNode.next = head;
    this->head = newNode;     // this->head = &newNode;
    delete newNode;           // (newNode is deleted automatically !)
}
```

When you use automatic storage, objects get destroyed as soon as they go out of scope. The method alone does not do much harm, but it leaves `this->head` as an invalid pointer (the object `newNode` was pointing to no longer exists when the method returns). Dereferencing an invalid pointer is undefinded behaviour, hence in all other methods that use the pointer anything could happen (including just what you expect, which is actually the worst incarnation of undefined behaviour, because you wont spot it until it is too late).

More in line with the original code, but much simplified, this is wrong for the same reason:

```
int* return_invalid_pointer() {
    int x = 3;
    return &x; 
}                      // <--- x's lifetime ends here
```

Here `x` lifetime is bound to the body of the function. You can return a pointer to a local variable, but this pointer has no meaning whatsoever outside of the function, because the value it pointed to no longer exists.

Comment: Why are you deleting newNode when we wanted to add a new node to the list? Wouldn't deleting it mean that linked list does not have an additional node?

Comment: @user87466 i am deleting it to demonstrate the problem in OPs code. The first snippet is a line by line translation of OPs `addValue2` (where also `newNode` is destroyed at the end of the function)

Comment: oh. does that mean that you are not deleting the node, but deleting only the pointer to it? (by doing `delete newNode`)?